# Simple Javascript to insert a div as the last element of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, joomla

I fixed my issue with CSS instead of Javascript, but I am still curious as to why I could not make it work with Javascript. I have this output from a cart software:

```
<div id="form-login-remember" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
  <label for="modlgn_remember">Remember Me</label>
  <input id="modlgn_remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" class="inputbox" value="yes" alt="Remember Me">
</div>
<div id="submit-login-button" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="Login">
</div>
```

Originally I had the `<label>` and the `<input>` both floated left which caused the button element underneath to slide up over the floated elements. I wanted to use javascript or jquery to insert a `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` as the last element in the first div listed above, `<div id="form-login-remember" style="margin-bottom:5px;"></div>` in order to force the parent div to have a height.

I tried these different methods, each to no luck:
1.

```
<script>
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    $("<div style='clear:both;'></div>").insertAfter("#modlgn_remember");
});
</script>
```

2.

```
<script>
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    $("#form-login-remember").append('<div style="clear:both;"></div>');
});
</script>
```

3.

```
<script>

var newDiv = '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';

$(window).load(function() {
  $('#form-login-remember').append(newDiv);
});

</script>
```

All three were inserted into my template before the closing body tag, and I'm already using jquery and those are linked from the head of my page. I'm learning javascript, can someone please point out what I've done wrong? Currently on the [homepage](http://themagicapple.com) of the site, I have option #3 still active but it's not inserting the div to clear:both...?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your problem lies not in how you were attempting to append the div, but usage of `load`.  Your current code results in a js error.  As seen [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/), jQuery's `load` is used to retrieve data (from a server) and output it into the desired element.

`$(document).ready()` is probably what you are looking for.

Here's a working example using your code (with document ready) from #3: https://jsfiddle.net/aecoadny/

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, now I understand the difference between the $(document).ready() function and the $(window).load() function.

Comment: Sorry, hit enter and it posted, I also removed the var = newDiv, and inserted the html string directly and it worked. Before when I had it with the variable it output the string name of the variable instead of the div.